# calabash-android - What does resign do?

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I am new to using calabash-android to test Android applications.

What does the `calabash-android resign name-of-my.apk` do?

Thanks

Comment: For others who are confused, perhaps "re-sign" would have been a better term than "resign".  It signs the apk again; it doesn't relinquish it.

Comment: @slindsey3000 resign will do sign your apk with your current machine android debug keystore more info please check this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqW94bvcuns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resign is used if you need to sign the app to match your keystore.
Copied from GitHub docs https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Running-Calabash-Android

Instead of resigning you could also consider copying your debug keystore to your folder.

> The apk calabash android runs must be signed with the same keystore as
>   the test-server.
>
> Use the command: calabash-android resign  to resign your
>   application.
>
> Building the test-server using calabash-android build  will build
>   the test-server and sign it with the same key as the application you
>   are testing.

Comment: The `calabash-android setup` command now lets you specify the path to an alternate keystore (e.g. the one you built your app with).  This has meant for me that I don't **need** to resign the app, as calabash can build the test server with the same keystore. I'm running v 0.5.15.