# Not able to build Android calabash environment on windows

Tags: java, android, eclipse, environment, calabash

For building the environment I've installed/use **OS Windows 8.1, eclipse, Android SDK, JDK, ruby installer, DevKit installed**. Also I've set path for **ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME**. I've tried maximum ways to **resign JAR** but not getting that jar so I'm stuck at the point and unable to move forward. **did google** for my problem. Now I got confused what will be step by step execution to make my environment to run? Or shall I need to build this structure on Linux to make it easier run?

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is you are asking about. Is it that the app is signed wrong and you are trying to resign? Instead of resigning you can also copy over the keystore http://stackoverflow.com/a/27118995/1165581

Comment: This problem got solved and thanks too for your help.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open 'CMD' or 'CMD with Ruby'

Run the following command

```
cucumber --version
```

if cmd shows cucumber version, proceed to next step

```
calabash-android version
```

if cmd show calabash-android version, you're ready to run calabash-android testcase.

Then create a folder, cd to that folder and run these commands.

```
$ calabash-android gen  #this will create folder structure
$ calabash-android resign apk_path/<apkfile.apk>
$ calabash-android build apk_path/<apkfile.apk>
$ calabash-android console apk_path/<apkfile.apk>
```

You will see interactive ruby editor, now type the following command

```
$ start_test_server_in_background  # app will install in connected device.
```

Then

```
$ query("*")
```

Now you can see all the elements in your android application!!

If you face any error/issue in any steps, your setup may be incomplete.