# calabash-android within travis

Tags: android, continuous-integration, travis-ci, calabash-android

I am trying to get calabash-android running within travis. calabash-android works fine within my machine without any problems. I have the following travis.yml:

```
    language: android
jdk: oraclejdk8
before_cache:
  - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/
    - $HOME/.gradle/daemon
    - $HOME/.gradle/native
env:
  global:
    # wait up to 10 minutes for adb to connect to emulator
    - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20
    - SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT=40

android:
  components:
    - platform-tools
    - tools
    - build-tools-23.0.3
    - android-23
    - extra-android-support
    - extra-android-m2repository
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-23

before_install:
  # install ruby 2.0.0
  - rvm install 2.0.0
  # install calabash-android
  - gem install calabash-android

before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force --name test --target android-23 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window -no-boot-anim &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 & #for unlocking as "powerkey"
  - sleep 3 # give screen some time to become unlocked
  - ./gradlew clean assembleDebug -PdisablePreDex --continue --stacktrace

script:
  - calabash-android resign /home/travis/build/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
  - calabash-android run /home/travis/build/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
```

It works with the 1st scenario of the feature and then once it starts 2nd scenario, it shows this error:

```
App did not start (RuntimeError)
 ./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
```

Any ideas? or suggestion?

Comment: There could be many reasons why the app does not start. I suggest running adb logcat while trying to start it to see what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Delete `-no-boot-anim` option, `android-wait-for-emulator` script depends on boot animation to detect when the emulator is ready.

This is a great explanation I recommend: [Detecting when emulator is ready to be used](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/starting-and-stopping-android-emulators/)

> The second step is to wait for emulator to fully boot, so it can be
>   used to run some code. This turned out to be the most tricky part.
>   Especially for emulators with API Level 11+ (11-14 at the time of
>   writing).
>
> First, emulator should connect to adb and will be listed as “offline”.
>   In this state emulator does not accept any shell commands. And nothing
>   can be done in this state. This part is usually very stable and I
>   haven’t seen the case when emulator was started but never connected to
>   adb. Of course if some error occurs, it won’t connect to adb. So
>   timeout should be used here to detect abnormal delays or hangs.
>
> Next state device goes to called “device” state. This is when device
>   is booting. As soon as it had booted, device goes to “online” state.
>   This is when system starts booting and normal operation of emulator
>   goes in.
>
> From the moment device goes to “device” state, adb shell can be used
>   to execute different commands on device and query some useful
>   information about its state.
>
> I’ve found several properties that should be tracked in order to
>   reliably detect when device is ready. The first property is called
>   dev.bootcompleted. As soon as device completes booting this property
>   will be set to 1.
>
> After dev.bootcompleted is 1, next property called sys.boot_completed
>   should be tracked. It will be set to 1 as soon as system completed
>   booting (this is usually when BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent). This
>   property is only set on emulators with API Level 9 or higher. On 8 and
>   lower this property is never used (and shouldn’t be tracked).
>
> But emulator is still not ready, even when sys.boot_completed is set
>   to 1. You’ll notice that boot animation will still run for some
>   (significant) period of time. And only then UI will appear. But
>   luckily there is a way to detect this event too. For this we need to
>   track value of init.svc.bootanim property. This property keeps state
>   of boot animation service, that will be stopped as soon as UI appears.
>   In other words, **as soon as init.svc.bootanim has value stopped, its
>   safe to assume that emulator is running and ready to be used**.

Using `-no-boot-anim` the value is `stopped` before your emulator is fully-booted:

```
# Originally written by Ralf Kistner <ralf@embarkmobile.com>, but placed in the public domain

set +e

bootanim=""
failcounter=0
timeout_in_sec=360

until [[ "$bootanim" =~ "stopped" ]]; do
  bootanim=`adb -e shell getprop init.svc.bootanim 2>&1 &`
  if [[ "$bootanim" =~ "device not found" || "$bootanim" =~ "device offline"
    || "$bootanim" =~ "running" ]]; then
    let "failcounter += 1"
    echo "Waiting for emulator to start"
    if [[ $failcounter -gt timeout_in_sec ]]; then
      echo "Timeout ($timeout_in_sec seconds) reached; failed to start emulator"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  sleep 1
done

echo "Emulator is ready"
```

---

Now I was doubting due to the first scenario works (I never used calabash-android) but I see that it doesn't depend on the emulator being ready:

[calabash-android - What does resign do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109585/calabash-android-what-does-resign-do)

> The resign is used if you need to sign the app to match your keystore.
>   Copied from GitHub docs
>   https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Running-Calabash-Android
>
> Instead of resigning you could also consider copying your debug
>   keystore to your folder.
>
> The apk calabash android runs must be signed with the same keystore as
>   the test-server.
>
> Use the command: `calabash-android resign <apk>` to resign your application.
>
> Building the test-server using calabash-android build will build the
>   test-server and sign it with the same key as the application you are
>   testing.

The second scenario does it:

[Running test](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android)

> To run your test: `calabash-android run <apk>`
>
> Calabash-android will install an instrumentation along with your app
>   when executing the app. We call this instrumentation for "test
>   server". The "test server" has special permission that allows it to
>   interact very closely with your app during test. Everytime you test a
>   new binary or use an upgraded version of calabash a new test server
>   will be build. The test server is an intrumentation that will run
>   along with your app on the device to execute the test.

Perhaps exist other issues in this case but [fixed the same issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952560/1009132) deleting `-no-boot-anim`.